# Using Java to upload file to remote server

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload, httprequest

I am writing a java automation. This automation will be located on it's own server and be making rest calls to the separate app server.

My problem is that for some of the cases I need certain files uploaded to a specific folder on the app server.

I would like to incorporate this file upload process right into the automation before any calls are made. The app server is set up as just an http server (ip address and credentials will be changing everyday).

I have done some research and think using a java http servlet to perform this could be done - however I do not personally have experience using a servlet before and examples I have found I don't think are exactly what I am looking for.

Let me know if this is a feasible task or if a better method can be done? Any links or examples how to perform this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just du make things clear - you will have the setup: a external automation - and an http server. and the automation will upload files to the http server?

Comment: the HTTP Server has the possiblilty to run PHP? Because you also need something which will store the file.

Comment: I am trying to find a way to do this without changing anything on the http sever side.

Comment: The thing is you need something which handles the file on the server - becuase you can't store something from your local machine without it.

Comment: So - Do you have PHP available on that http server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make things clear: You **must** have a server side component which handles your Fileuploads, if it would possible I would now store all my files on random server around the world. The component which handles the file can be a Java Servlet (for example a simply Jersey backend) - but that would be a big overhead for *store this file somewhere on my server*. I would suggest you to use PHP for this task.

For this you can use something like this:

```
<?php 
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    $path = $_POST['path'];
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $info = pathinfo($name);
    $ext = $info['extension']; // get the extension of the file
    $target = $path.$name;
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target);
    http_response_code(200);
?>
```

This will allow you to store a file somewhere according to the path you print as form data parameter.

To achieve this you can use this simple class (https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request):

```
package com.dominikangerer.q29679878;

public class HttpRequest {
    ...
}
```

And use it like:

```
package com.dominikangerer.q29679878;

import java.io.File;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HttpRequest("http://example.com/storeFile.php", "POST")
        .part("file", "file.jpg", new File("/your/file.jpg"))
        .part("path", "/the/path/it/should/be/stored/on/the/server/")
        .code();
    }

}
```

You can find this example (also with the exact file from the library posted above in here: https://github.com/DominikAngerer/StackoverflowJavaAnswers/tree/master/src/main/java/com/dominikangerer/q29679878

**Summary**

1. Without a server side component which handles your files it is **not** possible.
2. PHP would be the easiest way to achieve such a solution - no need for a servlet which would also need an application server (tomcat or similar) and much more configuration.
3. For all Http Requests You can simply use https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request in java.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it should help

Comment: If you need additional help - let me know.